# Ripple to Paket -- is there a better way?

Tags: nuget, ripple, paket

I'm in the process of converting a handful of projects from ripple to Paket.  The way I do this is install Paket, then take my ripple.config and copy my sources and nugets over to my paket.dependencies, taking care to == the versions that I have fixed.  Then I .paket/paket install over and over and over again trying to resolve versioning errors that come up from that.

After that, I open all my .csproj files and add an extra ..\ to all the HintPaths before opening my project and manually resolving whatever errors pop up.

Is there a better way to do this?  I know there's a ripple-to-paket converter but I not only couldn't get it to work, but many people I work with say that it's terrible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## 1 add a `paket.references` file in each project's folder

In each of your project files' folder, you should create a `paket.references` and list there the package name (only, the other info is kept consistent in your `paket.dependencies` in your root folder).

## 2 make sure the actual reference are handled with paket

you can manually remove the reference in the project files (either from VS or edit the project file), and call `paket install` which will add them (according to `paket.references` in the project's folder) with an additional `<Paket>True</Paket>` node (making it clear that this reference is handled by paket itself)

I think this is it.